# How to get values in this json object in ext js?

Tags: json, extjs, textfield

I try to get values and put in a textfield. return json is ;

```
Object { info=[1]}
```

in this

```
info[Object { name="name", another ="another"}]
```

clearly ;

```
{"info":[{"name":"name","another":"another"}]}
```

i do ;

```
var resp = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
txtName.setValue(resp.info);
```

and in text field it shown [Object object]

How to i get name and another values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because response.info is a root level node in your response which contains an array of objects:

```
[{"name":"name","another":"another"}]
```

So to use a value from this object in the text box (as it needs a string value) you need to access the object in this array and then extract the value from whichever key you want so to get the name value in the text field you would use:

```
txtName.setValue(resp.info[0].name);
```

As a side note, usually you would use an ExtJS Store with a proxy configured to retrieve and store data from the server (if returned in this type of JSON like structure). On the store config you would configure the root property to the tell the store reader which named property in the response contains the data. So in this case 'info' is the root where your data can then be found. The store reader would then loop through the objects in the array and create records for each in the store for the rest of the application to use.